# Judge the positive definiteness of $x^T A x$

Tags: quadratic-forms

Consider an asymmetric matrix $A \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times n}$ with eigenvalues $\lambda \in {\mathbb C}^+$, and $x \in {\mathbb R}^n$. I am not sure if the quadratic form $x^T A x$ is positively definite.

PS: This question is equivalent to judge the positive definiteness of $A^T + A$ given $\lambda(A) \in {\mathbb C}^+$. But I am not sure if it is correct or not.

Thanks very much!

Comment: It's easy to rewrite the quadratic form in terms of a symmetric matrix.  Do you know ways to check whether that symmetric matrix is positive definite?

Comment: @BrianBorchers Sorry, I have re-edited the question. The original one is trivial.

Comment: Since $A^T+A$ is symmetric, all eigenvalues are real ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, $\lambda(A^T+A) \in {\mathbb R}$. But I am not sure if $\lambda(A^T+A) \in {\mathbb R}^+$.

Comment: What is $\mathbb C^+$?

Comment: @user251257 ${\mathbb C}^+ := \{x\colon Re(x) > 0\}$